# Bash executing bash command

Tags: bash

I have problem running bash command in bash.

### Simple:

```
C="ls"
$C
```

works

```
angel@php56:/tmp$ C="ls"
angel@php56:/tmp$ $C
testFile1
```

---

### Complicated

```
C="bash -c \"ls\""
$C
```

works

```
angel@php56:/tmp$ C="bash -c \"ls\""
angel@php56:/tmp$ $C
testFile1
```

---

### More complicated

```
C="bash -c \"bash -c 'ls'\""
$C
```

doesn't work

```
angel@php56:/tmp$ C="bash -c \"bash -c 'ls'\""
angel@php56:/tmp$ $C
-c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
-c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

same for `C="bash -c \"bash -c \\\"ls\\\"\""`

```
angel@php56:/tmp$ C="bash -c \"bash -c \\\"ls\\\"\""                                                                                                                                                                                               
angel@php56:/tmp$ $C                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
-c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'                                                                                                                                                                                          
-c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Why I can run bash in bash, but cant bash in bash in bash :)
May be something with quotes ? Online code: [click](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_bash_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMcHNCeVhtMURkSFU)

Comment: [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the order of operations with word splitting vs parameter expansion.
It works with `eval`:

```
eval "$C"
```

This gets very tricky very quickly.  The best way to deal with dynamic commands that don't include pipes or other redirection is to use arrays:

```
C=(bash -c "bash -c 'ls'")
"${C[@]}"
```